# Extending native libraries in a SimpleSAMLphp module

Tags: php, saml

I have been working with SimpleSAMLphp for a while now. I haven't been able to figure out the intended way to extend native SimpleSAMLphp libraries (i.e. those found in the `lib/` directory) from a custom module. Specifically I am trying to extend `lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/LDAP.php`.

I have tried the following method. I created a module Foo `modules/Foo`. Created an `enable` file in its root. I then created `modules/Foo/lib/Auth/Source/LDAP.php`. This is the file's contents:

```
<?php
   class sspmod_Foo_Auth_Source_LDAP extends SimpleSAML_Auth_LDAP 
   {

     public function __construct($hostname, $enable_tls = TRUE, $debug = FALSE, $timeout = 0, $port = 389) 
     {
       die('test');
       parent::__construct($hostname, $enable_tls, $debug, $timeout, $port);
     }
   }
?>
```

I would expect to see a white screen with `die` as the only output if this library was working. But I don't.

I've checked the documentation, but it simply isn't great. So how do I do this? Is there a good how-to out there that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best place to ask is the forum group - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/simplesamlphp.

Comment: You probably need to go with [custom modules](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-modules)